# How to configure pig to access data via WebHDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, hadoop2, webhdfs

I am new to hadoop so please pardon me if this question is a blunder. I am trying to configure pig to use webhdfs to get data. I dont know how to do this I tried:-

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS","webhdfs://<uri>:50070");
properties.putAll(ConfigurationUtil.toProperties(conf));
```

I then passed this property object(properties) to the properties object in the main file of pig. However this doesn't seem to work. Any access to hdfs just times out without response. Can someone tell me how this is done?

Comment: From where are you running Pig?  The LOAD command grabs data from HDFS on the same cluster. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/basic.html#load

Comment: I am trying to interface pig to a remote cluster @HendPro12

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error i think i might have resolved the issue. the problem was not with the configurations passed(I could have just kept a core-site.xml on my classpath,with the fs.defaultFS property as above, by the way). The problem was the pig script file which I was trying to run had something like:-

```
REGISTER 'hdfs://<uri>:9000/filename.jar'
```

When it should have been

```
REGISTER 'webhdfs://<uri>:50070/filename.jar'
```

Not sure if that was pretty obvious and I wasted your time. Sorry for that.